# I'm having trouble with arrays of function pointers in C

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a silly little program, and I've run into a wall. The code in question is here:

```
double(*operf[NOPERS])() = {addf,subf,mulf,divf}
```

Which I've also done as

```
double(*operf[NOPERS])(double,double) = {addf,subf,mulf,divf}
```

When I run the program in main, using `printf("%f\n", (*operf[0])(2,3));`, I get the expected result (5), but when I call it from another place, I get gobbletygook. I know that this is possible in C and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've seriously looked at all of the other answers, and they seem to be doing exactly what I'm doing.

EDIT:
Here's the code in question. Didn't want to drown you all in code so I sort of went the opposite way haha.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// #include <math.h>

#define SE(X,Y) (strcmp(X,Y)==0)

#define STACKSIZE 1024
double snums[STACKSIZE];
int snums_ctr=0;
int sopers[STACKSIZE];
int sopers_ctr=0;

#define Push(STACK, DATA) STACK[STACK##_ctr++]=DATA
#define Peek(STACK) STACK[STACK##_ctr-1]
#define Pop(STACK) STACK[--STACK##_ctr]

#define ABF(NYM,DEF) double NYM (a,b){ return DEF ; }
ABF(addf,a+b);
ABF(subf,a-b);
ABF(mulf,a*b);
ABF(divf,a/b);
//ABF(pwrf,pow(a,b));

int indexOf(char**ss,char*s) {
    int i=0;
    while(*ss){
        if(SE(*ss,s)) {
            return i;
        }
        i++;ss=&ss[1];
    }
    return -1;
}

#define NOPERS 5

int operp[NOPERS] = {1,1,2,2,3};
int operprec[NOPERS] = {0,0,0,0,1};
char* opers[NOPERS+1] = {"+","-","*","/","**"};
char* cs(char* s) {
    int n=strlen(s);
    char*r=malloc(n+1);
    memcpy(r,s,n+1);
    return r;
}

char* gs(int n) {
    char c = getchar();
    char*r;
    if(c=='\n'){
        c=0;
        r=malloc(n+1);
    }
    else{
        r=gs(n+1);
    }
    r[n]=c;
    return r;
}
typedef double(*oper_f)();

void rpn(oper_f* operf) {
    printf("Entering RPN mode...\n");
    while(1) {
        char* raw = gs(0);
        int idx = indexOf(opers, raw);
        if(idx != -1) {
            double b = Pop(snums);
            double a = Pop(snums);
            double c = (*operf[idx])(b,a);

            printf("%f %s %f = %f %f\n", a,raw,b,(float)(double)c, addf(2,2));
            Push(snums, c);
        }
        else {
            Push(snums, atof(raw));
        }
        free(raw);
    }
}


int main() {
// operf[4] = &pwrf;
    oper_f operf[NOPERS] = {&addf,&subf,&mulf,&divf,NULL};
    printf("%f\n", (*operf[0])(2,3));
    printf("MODE? ");
    char* mode = gs(0);
    if(SE(mode,"rpn")||1) {
        rpn(operf);
    }
    free(mode);
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's hard to offer any help.

Comment: Could you post the code, or at least explain where you're declaring the array of pointers and how it's being passed to the function which calls it? It's hard to help without a minimal context.

Comment: Any warnings at compile time?

Comment: None at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mr.Branch I just added all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. It was a really silly error. I typed:

```
#define ABF(NYM,DEF) double NYM (a,b){ return DEF ; }
```

When I should have typed

```
#define ABF(NYM,DEF) double NYM (double a,double b){ return DEF ; }
```

Adding `std=99` as suggested helped me diagnose this problem. I think I need sleep.

Comment: Good to know you were able to fix it!!

Answer (score 0):

Example for array of funcs:

```
int f() {
  return 1;
}

int g() {
  return 2;
}

typedef int (*PFUNC)();

int main() {
  PFUNC pf[2] = {&f, &g};
  pf[0](); // return 1
}
```

Comment: I just tried that. It didn't work at all for some reason. If it helps, when I try to initialize the array outside of main I get a "not computable at load time" error, but that shouldn't affect it when I'm initializing in main.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Did it not compile? What's your system and compiler?

Comment: Linux Mint 17.3, gcc, standard stuff. The output I got was `2.000000 + 3.000000 = 20655140.000000` on an example run.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I normally do this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef float (*math_op)(float, float);

float addf(float f1, float f2) { return (f1 + f2);}
float multf(float f1, float f2) { return (f1 * f2);}
float divf(float f1, float f2) { return (f2 != 0 ? f1/f2 : NAN);}
float subf(float f1, float f2) { return (f1 - f2);}

int main(void)
{
  math_op opsf[] = {addf, multf, divf, subf};

  printf("sum of 1.0 and 3.5 is %f\n", opsf[0](1.0, 3.5));

  return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles cleanly on Windows 7 using gcc-4.8.3 using the command line `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall temp.c -o temp`.  And give the following output:

```
Q:\>gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall temp.c -o temp
Q:\>temp.exe
sum of 1.0 and 3.5 is 4.500000
Q:\>
```

If you are still having problems, please provide the system and compiler you are using, as well as a copy of your code.